# Getting the WKID/EPSG code as dynamic text in ArcGIS Pro Layouts

Tags: arcgis-pro, layouts, epsg, dynamic-text

I'm trying to get the WKID/EPSG code of the Coordinate System/projection used in the map as dynamic text in a ArcGIS Pro layout.
It should look something like this:

ETRS 1989 UTM Zone 33N N-zE (**EPSG: 5653**)

I can access the name through property="sr" srProperty="pcs",
but srProperty="factoryCode" or "fc" does not work.

I can access a whole bunch of parameters through the predefined spatial reference dynamic text, but the EPSG code is missing in this list.

Is there any way to find the EPSG code automatically?

EDIT:
Version: ArcGIS Pro 2.9.3

Comment: 2.2.0 is an *ancient* Pro build, which was patched three times in the year of its release (2018) and has since been Retired. You really ought to test your  desired functionality with a currently supported release.

Comment: Sorry, I'm using ArcGIS Pro 2.9.3 - looked it up wrong at the top of the info screen.
So this is a current problem.

Comment: Doesn't look like it out of the box, perhaps submit an [ArcGIS Pro Idea](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-ideas/idb-p/arcgis-pro-ideas) suggesting that factory code be exposed as an `srProperty` in the dynamic text spatial reference tags.